# Using Switch Statements to determine div background-color

Tags: php

I am building a percentage bar for my website based on pre-defined numbers (not server load percentage). When I use my `switch` statements to determine the color (based on "percentage range") it has the correct percentage, but the wrong color.

**My `php`**

```
$max = 250000;
$heat = 200000; //$_SESSION['warrents'];
$percent[0] = ($heat / $max) * 100;
if ($percent[0] > 100) { $percent[0] = 100; }

switch ($percent[1]) {
    case ($percent[0] < 25):
        $percent[1] = "green";
        break;
    case ($percent[0] >= 25 && $percent[0] <50):
        $percent[1] = "yellow";
        break;
    case ($percent[0] >= 50 && $percent[0] <75):
        $percent[1] = "orange";
        break;
    case ($percent[0] >= 75):
        $percent[1] = "red";
        break;
}
echo $percent[0]." ".$percent[1];
```

The `echo` says **80 green**

80 is correct; however, it should be red, not green. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course as soon as I posted this I figured out my problem:

```
switch ($percent[1]) {
```

should be

```
switch ($percent[0]) {
```

Thanks for those who looked!

Answer (score 0):

I needed a percentage bar on the site I am working on at the moment; It is currently on my development domain, so you can [check it out](http://sala123.ml) and see yourself (Yours can look however you want).

The following code will take a percentage value and return a color value from red-amber-green:

```js
function getColorFromPercent(percent) {
  colors = [
    'FF0000',
    'FF1000',
    'FF2000',
    'FF3000',
    'FF4000',
    'FF5000',
    'FF6000',
    'FF7000',
    'FF8000',
    'FF9000',
    'FFA000',
    'FFB000',
    'FFC000',
    'FFD000',
    'FFE000',
    'FFF000',
    'FFFF00',
    'F0FF00',
    'E0FF00',
    'D0FF00',
    'C0FF00',
    'B0FF00',
    'A0FF00',
    '90FF00',
    '80FF00',
    '70FF00',
    '60FF00',
    '50FF00',
    '40FF00',
    '30FF00',
    '20FF00',
    '10FF00'
  ];

  return '#' + colors.reverse()[Math.floor(parseFloat(percent) / (100 / colors.length))];
}

document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundColor = getColorFromPercent('23.8%');
```

```html
<div id="test">23.8%</div>
```

Good Luck, and If you have any issues - Let me know!